# Github - how to revert a pull from wrong branch

Tags: git, github, git-shell

I accidentally made a pull from a different branch, which shifted the `HEAD` saying:

`HEAD is now at 7c0208906 Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/origin/lorem-ipsum'`

Now, it keeps pulling from the `origin/lorem-ipsum` instead of `origin/master`

The files which got pulled also came with conflicts. Now its been a few days, new changes have been made on the master branch by others in the parent repository and i'm behind.

How can I revert the state of my repository back to how it was prior to my wrong pull and how can I simply shift the `HEAD` to previous state?

Please help, I'm stuck!

Comment: I don't remember all the steps but `git checkout <last valid commit id>` will revert the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The `git pull` command just runs `git fetch` (which is always<sup>1</sup> safe to do at any time) followed by `git merge`<sup>2</sup> (which is less so).  What you therefore need to recover from is your `git merge`.  But *this:*

> Now, it keeps pulling from the `origin/lorem-ipsum` instead of `origin/master`

... suggests that you told Git to *remember* that the "upstream" for `master` is `origin/lorem-ipsum`, not `origin/master`.  If that's true—you don't show the actual `git pull` you ran, nor the output of `git status` or `git branch -vv`, all of which would be useful clues here—then you *also* need to fix the upstream setting for your `master`.

Before we dive into the next step, there's one more thing to note:

> The files which got pulled also came with conflicts.

It's important to remember that Git doesn't pull *files*.  Git obtains, and then merges, *commits*.  Commits have files, and merging some commits can result in conflicts in files, so this might seem like a minor quibble, but it affects *how* you recover these things.

When you *do* get a merge conflict, *you* must resolve the conflicted files yourself, `git add` the results, and do a final `git commit` to make the merge commit.  (When you don't get a merge conflict, Git adds and commits the result for you.)  The `git status` command is ***extremely*** useful as it will tell you if you are in the middle of a conflicted merge, plus a lot of other good information.  Use it often.

#### Getting rid of a bad merge

If you're in the *middle* of a bad merge and you want the whole thing to go away, that's easy: just run `git merge --abort`.  That stops the merge process and puts everything back the way it was before you started.

If you've *finished* the merge, but it was bad and you want to get rid of it, that's harder, because you, or Git, finish a merge by making a new commit, and the whole point of commits is that they are permanent and unchanging.  Commits stick around "forever",<sup>3</sup> and new commits build upon previous commits, so it's *really* hard to get rid of a "middle" one.  It's much easier to get rid of a few "end" ones.

Let's draw some commits, including a merge, to see what we mean here.  Note that each commit has some incomprehensible hash ID (`1fc39a7` or `deadc0d` or some such).  To keep things clearer, we'll use single uppercase letters for each commit.  Note also that each commit has a *parent* commit, except for merges which have *two* parent commits.  We say that each commit "points back to" its parent (or, for a merge, parents plural):

```
... <-E <-F <-G <-K   <-- master (HEAD)
       \         /
        H <-I <-J   <-- origin/lorem-ipsum
```

Here `K` is our merge commit, pointing back to both `G` and `J`.  `G` is the commit that *was* the last commit on your `master`.  The name `master` now means ("points to") this commit `K`.  The name `origin/lorem-ipsum` points to commit `J`.  We also mark `master` with `HEAD`, to note that this is the branch we have checked-out now.

To *remove* `K` entirely, we can use `git reset`.  The `git reset` command can be quite destructive, so before you use it, run `git status` to make sure there's nothing you care about that you will lose.  (This is a recurring theme: **run `git status`.**)  Having made sure you are on `master`, that there's nothing else you can lose right now, and that `master` points to this merge commit `K` that you *do* want to lose on purpose:

```
git reset --hard master~1
```

The `~1` suffix tells Git to find the commit to which `master` points, and then *move back one step*.  That is, follow the arrow coming out of `K`.  If there are two arrows—there are, because `K` is a merge—Git should follow the *first* one, which is always the one pointing to the commit that was on `master` just *before* we did the merge.  So Git follows the arrow to commit `G`.

(Another way to do this is to use `git log` to find the actual hash ID for commit `G`, and run `git reset --hard <hash-id>`.  That's harder to type in, although cut-and-paste should work well.  But this "step back 1" with `~1` is easier, I think.)

What `git reset --hard` does is three things:

1. Change the branch to point to the selected commit.  That means `master` now names commit `G`, not `K`:

   ```
   ...--E--F--G   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          H--I--J   <-- origin/lorem-ipsum
   ```

   (I left out the internal arrows this time, as they're a pain to draw and don't give us much.  What happened to `K`?  It's still in there, in your repository, but it's in the recycling bin now, where it is hard to find and Git normally won't show it any more.)
2. The `reset --hard` step also resets Git's *index*.  Git's index is best described, I think, as "where you build up your next commit".  In normal cases, you want your index to match your *current* commit until you're starting to edit and `git add` changes to make a new commit.  So this is what you want: for your index to match commit `G`.
3. The `reset --hard` step also resets your *work-tree*, i.e., the place where you have all your files visible in the normal way so that you can work with or on them.  This throws away the merged versions from `K` and replaces them with the versions from `G`, which is also what you want.

Now it's as though the merge never happened.

Your *upstream* setting is still probably `origin/lorem-ipsum`, though.

#### Fixing or changing your upstream

To change the upstream setting of your current branch (still `master`), simply run `git branch --set-upstream-to=new-upstream`.  In this case, you want to set it to `origin/master` again, so:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

Now your current branch's (`master`'s) upstream is `origin/master`, so that `git pull` means "fetch, then merge with `origin/master`"—presumably what you want.

#### I recommend avoiding `git pull`

The `git pull` command is meant to be convenient.  And it *is* ... but this convenience is a sort of a trap.  If you knew you were doing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, you would have known to look at ways to undo a merge (and there are lots of existing SO answers for this).

Besides this, it's often better to use `git rebase` anyway.  So then you should run `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  You *can* get `git pull` to do this for you ... but sometimes rebase *isn't* the way to go; sometimes merge is better.  As you learn more Git, you will find that the merge-vs-rebase decision sometimes depends on *what you get when you fetch*.  In which case, how can you decide *in advance* whether to rebase or merge, before you see what gets fetched?

It's better to learn the separate steps first, I think.  Then, once you know them well, you can decide whether typing in just the one command (`git pull`) is worth the convenience vs the occasional headache when it goes wrong.  You will also know by then whether you want to merge or rebase by default, and you can set up `git pull` to do that.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are ways you can run `git fetch` manually that are not entirely safe, but they are very difficult to do.  You won't get this accidentally.

<sup>2</sup>You can direct `git pull` to use `git rebase` as its second step, instead of running `git merge` as its second step.  I assume, and what you show suggests, you did not do this.

<sup>3</sup>Well, that is, commits are permanent until you deliberately throw them out.  Then they are eventually tossed out for real with the rest of the rubbish, by `git gc`, the Garbage Collector, *after* a suitable waiting period during which you can recover them from the trash.